# Defining projection of Polar stereographic data in R via raster package

Tags: raster, coordinate-system, r, proj, stereographic

I'm having a hard time reading the following data into R: https://resources.marine.copernicus.eu/product-detail/ARCTIC_MULTIYEAR_BGC_002_005/INFORMATION

It uses a polar stereographic projection, and actually includes the following proj4 definition: `+proj=stere +lon_0=-45 +lat_0=90 +k=1 +R=6378273 +no_defs`

Unfortunately, `raster` is returned several error messages and fails to interpret this projection information (the plotted area should be centered around Greenland, not South Africa):

```
tmp <- brick(biofname, varname = "chl", level = 1)
# Warning messages:
# 1: In showSRID(uprojargs, format = "PROJ", multiline = "NO", prefer_proj = prefer_proj) :
#   Discarded ellps unknown in Proj4 definition: +proj=stere +lat_0=90 +lon_0=-45 +k=1 +x_0=0
# +y_0=0 +R=6378273 +units=m +no_defs +type=crs
# 2: In showSRID(uprojargs, format = "PROJ", multiline = "NO", prefer_proj = prefer_proj) :
#  Discarded datum unknown in Proj4 definition

plot(tmp, 2)
map("world", add = T, fill = TRUE, boundary = 1, col = 8)
```

[image]

The summary of the object is as follows:

```
> tmp
class      : RasterBrick 
dimensions : 124, 159, 19716, 3  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
resolution : 0.25, 0.25  (x, y)
extent     : -16.875, 22.875, -40.125, -9.125  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=stere +lat_0=90 +lon_0=-45 +k=1 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +R=6378273 +units=m +no_defs 
source     : cmems_mod_arc_bgc_my_ecosmo_P1M_1638805251473.nc 
names      : X524100, X524844, X525564 
z-value    : 524100, 524844, 525564 
varname    : chl 
level      : 1
```

Comment: That extent looks wrong. If it is in that coordinate system, then the units are metres and Greenland is bigger than that... What's the original downloaded data? (I've just registered on the site and I'm not sure how you've got the data you've shown here)

Comment: I can provide you the file if you like. basically, I selected the sub-region of (-75, -10, 55, 80), and included the first 3 months and first 4 depth layers. It's an .nc file of ~8 Mb

Comment: I've got one now. The ncdf dimensions in X and Y have a units attribute of "100 km". I think R or proj (the underlying projections library) is not getting this. Something non-standard might be going on here..

Comment: As per the [help/behavior] please do not include chit chat like thanks in your posts.